# How to retrieve image from RSS Feed Item description?

Tags: asp-classic, rss

I am binding a RSS Feeds using RSS Feed Reader i need to display the image from RSS Feed Item but image is wrapped inside RSS Feed Item Description.
Does any one know how to retrieve image from RSS Feed Item description? 
I am binding RSS Feed Using Classic ASP Script.

Answer (score 0):

With regular expression, with a quick search i found this regexp :

Pattern must be :

```
src=(?:\"|\')?(?<imgSrc>[^>]*[^/].(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:\"|\')?
```